# PHP :Anyone know Session handling like Facebook page does?

Tags: php, session

**Problem :**
**User** is already **logged in** 
so when I type 
local.test_php.com/form/

It takes me to Login page. local.test_php.com/form/index.php

But i want it to take it to my **home page** instead.(http://local.test_php.com/form/home.php)

what i want is like what facebook does when we type facebook.com (already logged in before) we r redirected to the news feed ... but in my case i get redirected to Login page(even if i'm already logged in) so i have to login again or type the url to get to the home page

I don't know how to customize sessions to always redirect to home page whenever user is logged in. It should not take me to login page in any condition.

Home page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<head>
    <title>My first PHP Website</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2 align="center">Home Page</h2>
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){

}else{
    header("location: index.php");
}

$user = $_SESSION['user'];
echo "<br>";
echo "WELCOME ".$user." ";
echo "<br>";
echo "Do you want to ";
print '<a href="logout.php" align="left">logout</a>';
echo " ?";
echo "<br>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a quick observation, you need to place your `header()` before any html / output, otherwise you'll get a "Headers all ready sent" error, apart from that you all ready got most of the logic right? if user isset or not empty, redirect to home?

Comment: @epodax can you please elaborate using code...appreciate it..!!

Comment: In your own provided code, you are all ready doing a check to see if the user is logged in, as far as I can see you are only redirected if you're not logged in?

Comment: @epodax  yes correct.
but what i want is like what facebook does

when we type facebook dot com we r redirected to the news feed ...

but in my case i get redirected to Login page so i have to login again or type the url to home page

Comment: So, a "remember me" function? set a cookie, or set the session to a later expire date.

Comment: sir ur not getting my question I don't want any of that ....It is the page redirection i'm having problem with ....in facebook you never get to login page unless you are logged out ....but in my case i'm which should not happen...so how to program that ..help me.. write some code which can do that...suggest any way

Comment: try outputting the value in the session and see if a value is being set

Comment: _"in facebook you never get to login page unless you are logged out "_ Yes, and that is a "remember me" function that stores a value that tells facebook that you are still logged in / stores your login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your code a littlebit, so it's more readable now.

First of all, when you want to use `header` function on your page, or start a session, you should do it before anyhing in the output buffer.

As you see, I removed the `echo` things, if you use an IDE as an editor, syntax highlighting help you to read the code, and be sure, it is valid.

The second thing, if you want to "remember" for user, when user closes all the browsers what stored the session variables, then you need to give a shot for [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). But first, fix the code.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("location: index.php");
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <head>
        <title>My first PHP Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 align="center">Home Page</h2>
<?php
    if (!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
        ?>
        <p>WELCOME <?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?></p>
        <p>Do you want to <a href="logout.php" align="left">logout</a>?</p>
        <?php
    }
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){

    }else{
        header("location: index.php");
    }

    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "WELCOME ".$user." ";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Do you want to ";
    print '<a href="logout.php" align="left">logout</a>';
    echo " ?";
    echo "<br>";

    ?>
    <html>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<head>
    <title>My first PHP Website</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2 align="center">Home Page</h2>
```

the problem with your code is that you want the header function after html output

Comment: please add $_SESSION['user'] = "user"; after the session_start so you are sure this session isset. this method works here.

Comment: user in quotes is a variable.?

Comment: no that will be the value so your output would be: "welcome user"

Comment: bro ur not getting my question I don't want any output i know how to get that ....It is the page redirection i'm having problem with ....in facebook you never get to login page unless you are logged out ....but in my case i'm which should not happen...

Comment: you'll have to replace $_SESSION['user'] with session_destroy(); to make sure you unset the session. then you can try to go to the header. sorry i got your question wrong.